# Make own dial-up ISP using broadband connection

Tags: linux, voip, isp, modem, dialup

So, I see no reason why this wouldn't be possible.  I have a Linux server (a Raspberry Pi to be exact) connected via Ethernet to a broadband ISP.  I want to be able to dial a number, have it go through the normal telephone network, onto the Internet via a VoIP provider (I know you can call a Skype user from a landline), to my Raspberry Pi, and then have the Pi connect me to the Internet.  I've found guides on making your own ISP, but they all involve a dedicated phone line on the server end.  Is there a way to do this with no modem on the server end?  I live in an area with a lot of people still on dialup, and if I pull this off I could make some extra money.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't work. Dialup is painful enough as it is that making it worse with a VoIP hop is a non-starter. To provide usable dialup service, you need a clean, digital 56Kbps path from your digital modem to the end user's local DAC.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this would work. It will be as difficult to get setup as faxing over VoIP. Then there's the problem of finding your modem equivalent. Asterisk comes to mind, that's ... weird. Analog to digital to analog to digital?

If you do get it setup, let us know how you did it.